# Which rails gem do I need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I just deployed a rails application to heroku after which my rails server no longer works.It gives the following error

```
bin/rails:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I ran `gem query --local` and saw that rails 4.1 was installed.Can someone explain to me what this error means and how to resolve it

Comment: Can you attach your Gemfile and your Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which rails is on your PATH... you probably installed are running on a mac that have an native rails.

Read this documentation to learn how to set your default rails instance.

http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html‎